# Page not found for a node that does exist?

Tags: nodes

I have created a module which includes a custom form. When the form is submitted the module uses `drupal_write_record` to insert the form contents into the database. The first `drupal_write_record` is to the node table. Using phpmyadmin I've looked into the node table and I can see there is a record where nid is 11. If I request `example.com/?q=node/11` I get a 'page not found' error.

Here is record 11 from the node table:

```
nid,vid,type,language,title,uid,status,created,changed,comment,promote,sticky,tnid,translate
11,NULL,game,und,Title,1,1,1365111019,1365111019,1,0,0,0,0
```

Why doesn't `example.com/?q=node/11` return the contents of this record as a page? Do I need to do something else?

Comment: How did you save this node?using content type or custom also if it is custom did you use node_save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write a node using a single [drupal_write_record()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7). Depending on how your content type is defined you will need to write to several tables. But you don't need to know the precise details because the right way to create a node is to use [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7) as Ahmed mentioned in his comment.